# Programmatically force selects an item in a primeng Listbox (p-listbox). Angular 2/PrimeNg

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-forms

I have a list which I displayed using a PrimeNg Listbox (p-listbox). It is a list of group in which I watch the changes of the selection by implementing the ngDoCheck lifecycle hook. Every changes under ngDoCheck I created a condition that will check if the selection is a specific group ("Group0"). If the user selects "Group0" I want to force the selection of p-listbox back to the previously selected group. I was able to determine the previously selected group  and equate that to selectedGroup but it's not working. Below is the code:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck{

    selectedGroup: any;
    groups: any [] = [];
    groupList: SelectItem [] = [] ;
    differ: any;

    constructor(private differs:  KeyValueDiffers) {
       this.groups = [
         {"groupId": 1, "groupName": "Group1"},
         {"groupId": 2, "groupName": "Group2"},
         {"groupId": 3, "groupName": "Group3"},
         {"groupId": 4, "groupName": "Group4"},
         {"groupId": 5, "groupName": "Group5"},
         {"groupId": 0, "groupName": "Group0"}
      ];
      this.differ = differs.find([]).create(null);
    }


    ngOnInit() {
      this.groups.forEach(gp=> this.groupList.push({label: gp.groupName, value: gp}));
      this.selectedGroup =  this.groups[0];
    }

    ngDoCheck() {
      var changesInSelectedGroup= this.differ.diff(this.selectedGroup);
      if (changesInSelectedGroup && this.selectedGroup!=undefined) {
            if(this.selectedGroup.groupId==0) {

              let previousVal: string = this.differ._appendAfter.previousValue;
              let currentVal: string = this.differ._appendAfter.previousValue;
              this.selectedGroup = this.groups.find(gp=> gp.groupName==previousVal);
             // alert('Group0 selected. Selection should go back to previously selected group');
            }
            console.log(this.differ._appendAfter.previousValue);
      }
    }
}
```

I created a plunkr for this. http://plnkr.co/edit/oLoCEMT4zxqCApUL4Isn?p=preview

Comment: So the `selectedGroup` is correct but visually, the `p-listbox` is not updating right?

Comment: yes exactly I don't know why the Listbox not updating

Answer (score 5):

Angular's `NgModel` directive communicates with the corresponding `ControlValueAccessor` as below:

[image]

So i would suggest to solve your problem as follows:

**template.html**

Add template reference variable to your `p-listbox` element

```html
<p-listbox #listBox [options]="groupList" [(ngModel)]="selectedGroup"></p-listbox>
```

**component.ts**

```typescript
ngDoCheck() {
   var changesInSelectedGroup= this.differ.diff(this.selectedGroup);
   if (changesInSelectedGroup && this.selectedGroup!=undefined) {
     if(this.selectedGroup.groupId==0) {

       let previousVal: string = this.differ._appendAfter.previousValue;
       let currentVal: string = this.differ._appendAfter.previousValue;
       this.selectedGroup = this.groups.find(gp=> gp.groupName==previousVal);
       // alert('Group0 selected. Selection should go back to previously selected group');
     }
     console.log(this.differ._appendAfter.previousValue);
  }
}
```

Override `onChange`(`onModelChange` in your case) event for `ControlValueAccessor`

```typescript
@ViewChild('listBox') accessor: Listbox;
@ViewChild('listBox', { read: NgModel }) model: NgModel;

ngOnInit() {
  ...
  this.accessor.registerOnChange = (fn: (val: any) => void) => {
    this.accessor.onModelChange = (val) => {
      if(val && val.groupId === 0) {
        this.model.control.setValue(this.model.value);
        return;
      }
      return fn(val);
    };
  }
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/EPjBq9eMg9ejsM7bOk1U?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I wanted to do. This solves my problem. :) I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: I have a lot of questions about this problem. Can I message you outside stackoverflow? .

Comment: I have a similar problem like this. I want to craete a custom input implementing ControlValueAccessor. Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658288/creating-a-custom-controlinput-using-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-2

Comment: I'm having a problem in declaring registerOnChange in oninit. I tried to console the listbox but getting undefined value. But when declare it on AfterViewInit thats when the time the listbox gets a value. But the detection of registerOnChange is not working.